# Wordpress ajax call is returning an entire page of html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have the following piece of javascript which runs in my wordpress site :

```
var PostData = "Action=refresh-cart";
                     jQuery.ajax({
                       dataType: "text",
                       type: 'POST',
                       url : location.href,
                       cache: false,
                       data : PostData,
                       complete : function() {  },
                       success: function(data) {
                         //   jQuery("#loading-img").hide();

                           // jQuery("#join-class-div-3").html(data);

                        }           
                });
```

The php is :

```
<?php 

  if(isset($_POST['Action'])) {
        $Action = $_POST['Action'];
        if($Action == "refresh-cart") {


           echo '<div id="stuff"><p> done LOL </p></div>'; 
            }
        }

    ?>
```

So I expect to be sent back :

```
<div id="stuff"><p> done LOL </p></div>
```

But instead I receive an entire page of html!? Why!?

Comment: So literally all that is on your php page is what you have above? What other html comes back or can you tell?

Comment: Your code seems to work as expected when I run it locally, is there some code outside of what you've included in your question that's initializing an HTML page?

Answer (score 1):

It will return **all** contents from the page rendered at your url "location.href"

Try adding a `exit()` to your php code to stop it after your echo.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['Action'])) {
    $Action = $_POST['Action'];
    if($Action == "refresh-cart") {
         echo '<div id="stuff"><p> done LOL </p></div>';
         exit;
    }
}
?>
<div>html content here will not be displayed</div>
```

Comment: The php actually has tons more but it's all wrapped around if  statements on the  action variable - so this should work right?

Comment: Ok so the problem is , location.href is : http://127.0.0.1:8080/wordpress/?page_id=7 so I think the request is flowing through many many php files. How can I find out what the URL of my specific wordpress plugin php file is?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was occuring because location.href was a high level URL, so wordpress was injecting loads of html around the ajax request.

Through altering location.url to a call to `plugins.url()` which is part of the wordpress PHP API - the AJAX call goes directly to my PHP page and I get the correct response :)

Comment: In the end though - I ended up using this method for ajax because otherwise I could not access wordpress APIs: http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins